# Why my pic18f458 send 0x00 by uart after recived a byte from pc?

Tags: uart, rs485, xc8

I wish to know is you can help. I'm trying to comunicate by rs485 a pic18f458 and my PC, like it show the image.

[image: esquematic]

This is what I want to happen:

1. Send a byte from PC to microcontroller.
2. The microcontroller read the byte.
3. The microcontroller send to PC the byte recived.
4. The microcontroller keep waiting other byte.

This is what it happens:

1. The PC send the byte 0x97 to microcontroller.
2. The microcontroller read the byte 0x97.
3. The microcontroller send to PC the byte 0x97.
4. The PC recive the byte 0x97.
5. The microcontroller send to PC the byte 0x00 and PC read 0x00 (it is repeated this step continuously).

Here is my code:

```
    // CONFIG1H
#pragma config OSC = HS         // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config OSCS = OFF       // Oscillator System Clock Switch Enable bit (Oscillator system clock switch option is disabled (main oscillator is source))

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON         // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config BORV = 25        // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (VBOR set to 2.5V)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
#pragma config WDTPS = 128      // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:128)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVR = ON        // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Full/Underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low-Voltage ICSP Enable bit (Low-Voltage ICSP enabled)

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-001FFFh) not code protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not code protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not code protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not code protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0001FFh) not code protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM not code protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-001FFFh) not write protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not write protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not write protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not write protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) not write protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0001FFh) not write protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM not write protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000200-001FFFh) not protected from Table Reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) not protected from Table Reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) not protected from Table Reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) not protected from Table Reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot Block (000000-0001FFh) not protected from Table Reads executed in other blocks)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#include <xc.h>

void main(void) {
    char dato;
    TRISC=0;
    TRISCbits.RC7 = 1;
    PORTC=0;
    /*
    INTCONbits.PEIE=1;
    INTCONbits.GIE=0;
    */
   
    //UART INIT
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 1;
    SPBRG = 129;
   
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0;
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;
   
    TXSTAbits.TX9 = 0;
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 0;
   
    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;
   
    PIE1bits.RCIE=1;
   
    while(1){
       
        if (PIR1bits.RCIF==1){
            // read the byte 0x97
            dato = RCREG;
            if (RCSTAbits.OERR){
                RCSTA1bits.CREN=0;
                RCSTAbits.CREN=1;
            }
           
            //Enable transmision MAX485
            PORTCbits.RC5 = 1;
            __delay_ms(100);
           
            //send to pc byte recivied.
            TXREG = dato;
            while(TXSTAbits.TRMT == 0);
           
            //Enable reception max485
            PORTCbits.RC5 = 0;
           
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I added a resistor from Rx to GND and it is solved. I don't know why.

Comment: Come back the error.

Comment: Put a pull-up resistor from RX to +5v. When your PIC drives the MAX485 RE & DE high to transmit, this disables the RO output resulting in it floating to an indeterminate value and your PIC thinking it's received another byte. The pull-up resistor will prevent this.